# Ruby Faraday gem adds Content-type when no body

Tags: ruby, api, content-type, faraday

I am using the Ruby [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) gem to make some requests to the Bitstamp API.

I want to make a [this](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/#account-balance) `post` request (to get my account balance) with an empty body. The problem that I'm having is that Faraday adds a `Content-type` header during the execution of the request, I suppose, in a middleware. The Bitstamp API doesn't permit the inclusion of the `Content-type` header when the body is empty, so I'm getting the following error:

```
BitstampClient::Error: Bitstamp error: 403 {"status": "error", "reason": "Content-Type header should not be present", "code": "API0020"
```

How can i exclude the `Content-type` header? I tested the same request in Postman, and it worked well. So i'm sure that this is the problem.

Comment: Which middleware are you using? There definitely are some middleware that add the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: My builder is the following:
`<Faraday::RackBuilder:0x000000401e9f2208 @adapter=Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp, @handlers=[Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded]>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My builder is the following: <Faraday::RackBuilder:0x000000401e9f2208 @adapter=Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp, @handlers=[Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded]>

Yes, the `UrlEncoded` middleware adds the `Content-Type` header. Docs:

> The middleware also automatically sets the Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
> https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/8f00640dd51da00c8ca09f29bca0a2b32c553925/docs/middleware/request/url_encoded.md

Comment: As you say, the problem was with this middleware. The solution was to empty the `@handlers` list. Thank you!